# Coinbase custom button in Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, coinbase-api

I'm trying to add a custom coinbase payment button in a google chrome extension.

I've gotten it to work in the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hqhLV/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

code = "65a580d7449cc35869c9bd0d49cf77bd";

function get_button_html(code) {
    var button_html = "<div class='coinbase-button' data-code='65a580d7449cc35869c9bd0d49cf77bd' data-button-style='none'></div>";

    return button_html;
}

function loadButton(code) {
    $('body').after("<a href='' class='my-custom-link'>Show Me The Modal!</a>", get_button_html(code));
};

loadButton(code);
$.getScript("https://coinbase.com/assets/button.js");

$('.my-custom-link').click(function () {
    console.log('coinbase_show_modal');
    $(document).trigger('coinbase_show_modal', '65a580d7449cc35869c9bd0d49cf77bd');
    return false;
});

$(document).on('coinbase_payment_complete', function (event, code) {
    console.log("Payment completed for button " + code);
    window.location = "/confirmation.html";
});
```

});

However, copying the code as a content script file in the extension. Any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: Isn't that code supposed to be secret? **If it is, editing the question is not enough. Flag the question for moderator attention (to later purge it completely) and delete it.** Also, it's already crawled by Google, so might as well invalidate that code.

Comment: Have you checked the javascript console for errors?

Comment: No errors. I've also inspected the elements and the iframe for the modal is there and loaded, but just doesn't show after the trigger.